# Transfer an entire Google Earth Engine assets to another Google Earth Engine account

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, google-earth-engine-python-api

I was using a Google Earth Engine(GEE) account and the corresponding Google Drive storage was very less for me.I extended the drive storage for my another Google account and activated GEE for that account. I had lots of data within different assets of previous account. For transferring them I'm following these procedure:

1. Share each asset with my second account.
2. Using ee.Image()/ee.FeatureCollection() etc.
   Is there any way to transfer an entire **Assets** at a time rather than transferring each files within it one by one?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, one way is to use the earthengine python API.
First create a new folder through the code editor for your destination folder.

Then you can run this peace of code in a jupyter notebook (or colab)

```
import ee
ee.Initialize()

# folder from where to copy
src_folder = "projects/earthengine-legacy/assets/users/username/old_folder"
# folder where to copy
dest_folder = "projects/earthengine-legacy/assets/users/username/new_folder"

# get all assets in the folder
assets = ee.data.listAssets({'parent': src_folder})

# loop through assets and copy them one by one to the new destination
for asset in assets['assets']:
    # construct destination path
    new_asset = dest_folder + '/' + asset['id'].split('/')[-1]
    # copy to destination
    ee.data.copyAsset(asset['id'], new_asset, True)
    # delete source asset
    ee.data.deleteAsset(asset['id'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't very satsfied by the vanilla method provided in the `ee.data` module so I coded it in [`geetools`](https://gee-tools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) plugin lib.

Using the `Asset` object, on can call the `move` methods directly from a folder and define a destination. All the children will be moved as well and deleted from the source location. It work recursively for any tree depth:

```py
import ee, geetools

src = ee.Asset("projects/bar/assets/foo")
dst = ee.Asset("projects/bar/assets/new_foo")
src.move(dst)
```

See more information in [`Asset` documentation page](https://gee-tools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/autoapi/geetools/Asset/index.html#geetools.Asset.Asset.move).